Why does Genesis not mention the creation of fire?
Scientists say that fire, in the form as we have it on planet earth is hardly seen in any other part of the universe.                          One of the earliest references to fire in OT is Gen 22:6 :

And  Abraham took the wood for the burnt offering and laid it on his son Isaac, and he took in his hand the fire and the knife. So the two of them walked on together.

< Of course, fire has been and is vital to the survival of human life, whether in the form of light or heat. But then, we do not find Genesis mentioning the creation of fire . How  do Bible scholars interpret the absence of such a reference ?

There are lots of relatively minor details that aren't explicitly mentioned. Why would you expect that this one specifically should be?

Fire seems to be something man can make from what God has made.  It is not a primary element and I suppose the first fire may have been the result of lightning bolts? So men would have thought God may have provided it? Not really something I have ever pondered. Water, land and sky and animals etc., seems more natural to provide a fabric of creation. Before understanding chemistry ancient philosophers imagined the universe was made of the elements fire, water, wood etc., and that is probably because they thought the stars were on fire and were fire gods. But that is a misconception.

I think that you mistake the Bible with a History and/or Science textbook. Bible focuses only on certain subjects, like the relation God and man, or God's plan for the salvation an mankind. There are many elements important for life, and it's ok that it does not mention them all.

Neither does it mention the invention of the wheel, or of fermentation, or of weaving, or of writing, or of sandals, or of many many other fundamental things of civilization.  What is so special about the case of fire?

The question is still a reasonable one. In the literary myths of early genesis you'd expect perhaps an explanation of fire. Certainly other religions of the age included the discovery of fire in their stories. The Bible associates fire often with divine actions in the OT as well.

Ray Butterworth, fire is an exclusive property of the earth which, according to Genesis, God fashioned for human beings. Of course, Adam and Eve survived on uncooked fruits, but Cain most probably cultivated grains and pulses  which required cooking. The ' discovery' of fire would have come at a later stage, but it did exist with Creation.

I think it makes sense, since the Greeks, for one, thought the creation of fire was a pretty important thing.  Also, Aaron's sons apparently had some "unholy fire" which was unpleasing to God - so even God has an opinion on the matter

BTW, the earliest explicit reference I can find to men using fire is Genesis 8:20, when Noah offers burnt offerings. Pedantically, the earliest reference to fire seems to be Genesis 3:24, i.e. the flaming sword guarding the Tree of Life. In any case, it seems likely that men had use of fire almost since the beginning, perhaps even since before the Fall. (As noted, it also seems likely that Abel used fire, even though not explicitly mentioned, and it is almost certain that Tubal-cain used fire.)

The ceremonial law speaks extensively about the use of fire to purify things and also its use in the context of the burnt offering, the major sacrifice.
In Genesis 4:4, "Abel also brought of the firstborn of his flock and of their fat portions." It does not explicitly mention fire, but the presentation of the fat portions in the law always involved fire. It is thus logical to infer that Abel presented a burnt offering.
A second reference that certainly implies fire is in Genesis 4:22, which says "Zillah also bore Tubal-cain; he was the forger of all instruments of bronze and iron." You cannot forge bronze and iron without fire.
These two people, Abel and Tubal-Cain (son of wicked Lamech), represent holy and unholy uses of fire. It is the first uses of fire rather than the actual discovery of fire that is recorded. It is in these uses that we see men pursuing their purposes, sacred and profane. The meaning and purpose of things is important in the Bible, less so the mechanics.

Agreed, the purpose of the Bible is to guide us towards salvation. Where fire came from is not helpful to that. But it is a very useful symbol to teach with. It is like God was in the old testament, it can give us warmth and shelter... or it can be destruction.

Considering that the primordial history section of Genesis is written in the form of literary myth (not false myth) it is not an unreasonable question to ask! So here is the first reference of fire.

After he drove the man out, he placed on the east side of the Garden of Eden cherubim and a flaming sword flashing back and forth to guard the way to the tree of life. (Genesis 3:24)

This logically means we knew what fire was before we were cast out of the garden of eden. Even if the flaming sword is symbolic or poetic, we knew what fire was before that event.

Well done! I overlooked the sword. Perhaps Adam and Eve told this story to their children, inspiring Tubal-Cain to work with metal to create his own sword.

Personally I don't agree with the literal version of the garden of eden being a place, it was symbolic, just like the sword is. But my point is still we knew what fire was.

Certainly it was a real place; why give details about its location and surrounding geography if it's "symbolic"? Equally certain, it was destroyed utterly in the Flood and no longer exists.

We can keep our debate about literalistic and literary interpretation within the chat :-) But as you point out regardless if it was symbolic or literally a place... it was destroyed and doesn't exist.

Honestly, just because I don't think it was relevant to mention it. If you read the account of Genesis 1, it also doesn't mention the creation of water. It says that God created the earth and the the Spirit hovered over the face of the deep. We just assume (rightly) that water was also created when the earth was created. And water is far more necessary for survival than fire.
It also doesn't mention the creation of Oxygen, which is more necessary even than water (although I suppose you could rightly argue that they are as vital as one another, just that you would live for slightly longer without water than you would without oxygen). There is a record of the atmosphere being created, but no mention of making it breathable. That is just assumed.
In like manner, we know now through observation of the sun, that the creation of fire must be assumed for the sun to be as it is. That is probably as close as you are going to get to a recorded creation of fire.
But to get to the reason, I think it is because the whole of scripture is actually pointing to Christ, and that is it's purpose. So fire is mentioned when it is relevant to that end, but otherwise it is left out. Even if you look in Genesis 1, you see prophetic pictures of Jesus popping up all over the place. The reference to the Spirit of God hovering over the face of the deep (a prophetic picture of a suitable dwelling place not being found for God, a picture expanded on in the dove that Noah sends out from the ark, and then completed with the Spirit descending onto Jesus 'as a dove' at His baptism); the light being created 2 days before the sun and moon were created (showing that it was something far more eternally significant than the light energy produced by the sun, a picture expanded upon again at Jesus death, that as the source of the Light of life was made sin, or darkened, for 3 hours, so also the sun lost it's power to share light); and the sun and the moon to rule over the day and night (a prophetic picture of Christ ruling his kingdom - the eternal day, as it would always be daytime to someone on the same orbit as the sun - and the moon being the demonstration of his Church on Earth - to rule over the night, in other words to be the 'light bearers' of the night [the time between the fall and the second return of Christ] - and the moon only being useful as a light if it is reflecting the light of the sun, just as we can only serve God on earth by reflecting Christ).
The list goes on and on, but in summary and as far as I understand it, specifically recording the creation of fire wasn't necessary to point to Jesus Christ and His Gospel of Salvation, and so it wasn't recorded.
I hope this helps,
God bless :)

Birdbrain, in my view, the relevance of incarnation in human form, of the Son of God, originated with the First Sin , sometime after the Creation. Had man not sinned, there would not be Christmas and Good Friday. Be that as it may, it may not be wise to assume that God the Father had Jesus in mind while creating the earth.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan Without Him who is Logos nothing was made that was made. All things were created in accord with Him. And all things were made by Him. And He was, in the beginning, with God. And God was the Logos. (Answer up-voted +1.)

@KadalikattJosephSibichan scripture seems to disagree with you. The verse that pops to mind is Revelation 13:8, which seems to say that the 'Book of Life of the Lamb slain' has been present at least 'from the foundation of this earth'
